# Search text in all columns of multiple sheets

Tags: google-sheets

Given many texts to look for, I want to search all my sheets in all columns if there's at least one partial case insensitive match then return true (or 1 or the sheet's name or whatever) and false otherwhise...

[image]

I didnt go far, I tried the following which searches one col in the next sheet (just one, yet to make it search in all of them):

```
=IF(FIND(A1,sheet1!A2:A1000)>0,"true","false")
```

I'm getting:

```
Error
An array value could not be found.
```

All suggestions/solutions are welcome to solve my whole problem as explained at the start

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need [`search`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094154?hl=en) (case-insensitive) instead of `find` (case-sensitive). Also, a few wrappers around it:

```
=max(arrayformula(iferror(search(A1, sheet1!A1:A1000)))) > 0
```

1. `iferror` ensures empty output instead of #N/A when the cell is empty or text cannot be found
2. `arrayformula` specifies that we work with an array
3. `max` returns the maximum (so it will be positive if at least one cell matched)
4. Comparison >0 will return TRUE or FALSE; no `if` statement needed.

The above works for multiple columns at once: you can use `sheet1!A1:Z1000` and so on.

The results from multiple sheets can be pooled together by addition prior to comparison:

```
=max(arrayformula(iferror(search(A1, sheet1!A1:Z1000)))) + max(arrayformula(iferror(search(A1, sheet2!A1:Z1000)))) > 0
```

Comment: Amazing, thanks a lot... However, the multiple sheets solution is 'ugly', I came accross a formulation like this `{sheet1!$A$1:$Z; sheet2!$A$1:$Z}`... It takes some time to load due to the many sheets I have I guess, but It's working good so far... If you have no remark regarding this, then consider the question solved :-)